# Where to expand Woocommerce API?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a local wordpress/woocommerce installation, and I need to look at the API itself so I can make some changes and adjust it to my needs.

Which files should I be looking for?

Comment: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/

Comment: I managed to do it from within the woocommerce/api/* classes on the plugin. Is there a more elegant way to do this, @AvinashBabu? Remember that I am looking to expand the API. 

Also, do you know if the API supports passing of site_id for multisites? I can't find that on the docu.

Comment: you can use get_site_id()  ??